# Workday Rest API - POST Call For Work Email Change

Tags: workday-api

I currently have a use case where I need to update work email for users in Workday using Workday Rest API. I have added all the required scopes and BP permissions but still have been receiving the below error when I try to do the POST staffing/workers/{ID}/workContactInformationChanges

{

"error": "not found: staffing",

"code": "S21"

}

Is there any additional permissions that need to be enabled in order to get access to the staffing api collection?

Answer (score 0):

When I was setting up the connection to Workday I had included too much info in the connection URL and was getting this same error,
ex: `https://wdX-impl-servicesX.workday.com/ccx/api/v1/XXXx1`

Here is what I shortened it to:
ex: `https://wdX-impl-servicesX.workday.com`

This allowed the API call to construct the rest of the URL... otherwise it was constructing the URL incorrectly like this:
`https://wdX-impl-servicesX.workday.com/ccx/api/v1/XXXx1/ccx/api/v1/XXXx1/filename`

Comment: I undid the formatting which drew the wrong kind of attention and on the side clarified that this supposed to be example code instead of clickable links, for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think based on API document, the url should be POST /ccx/api/staffing/v5/{tenant_name}/workers/{ID}/workContactInformationChanges, however, I am still getting a "permission denied" error